# Conditional formatting to include OR statements

Tags: excel

I have two columns of drop down lists. The entry in Col A needs to affect how Col B can be entered. Basically the logic is, if you've have not selected "" or N/A in Col. A, then you can enter a value from the drop down in Col. B, otherwise no need to input anything in Col. B.

Since I have drop downs, I dont want to use formulas but conditional formatting which will highlight to the user that they do not need to enter information into Col B if certain conditions are met in Col A

The formula I have for Conditional Formatting in Col. B is

`=$A1<>"N/A"`

What I need is:

`=$A1<>OR("N/A", "")`

But that leads to an error

Including both options will make my Sheet look nicer, because the spreadsheet I have now can have multiple row entries, and right now conditional formatting is kicking in because A2-A1000 are blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the idea right but not the syntax.

it should look like something like this :

```
=AND($A1<>"N/A"; $A1<>"")
```

Might be a comma instead of `;` depending on your excel settings

Comment: I tried that but the conditional formatting is kicking when I choose N/A or ""

Comment: Ah, thank you, I didn't think this through! I updated my answer with `and`, it will check if it's not equal to N/A and not equal to "" so it should work proprely